# HapiJS + create-react-app + webpack-dev-middleware configuration

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, hapi.js, webpack-dev-middleware

I am currently using a `create-react-app` with HapiJS as a proxy for serving the static files.

This is how my current setup looks like:

```
//server.js
const server = new Hapi.Server({
        port: process.env.PORT || 80,
        routes: {
            files: {
                relativeTo: Path.join(__dirname, '../build')
            }
        }
    });
await server.register(Inert);
server.route(routes); // comes from an array of routes defined in react-routes.js
await server.start();
console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
```

```
//react-routes.js
//All the routes mapped here should return an index.html file.
//React will take care of routing.
const routes = [
    { method: 'GET', path: '/home', config: fileHandler }
    { method: 'GET', path: '/account', config: fileHandler }
    ]

const fileHandler = {
    handler: (req, res) => {
        return res.file('index.html');
    }
}
```

I am using `nodemon` in development to run the server and `react-scripts start` to run the react-app.
Now the problem is, the HapiJS server only serves the static files from the `build` folder generated using `react-scripts build`. I understand that in order to connect to the webpack build, I need to use a middleware for HapiJS.

Looking at the [webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#using-webpack-dev-middleware), I see that it needs a reference to the `webpack.config.js` file. But I am not at liberty to use `eject` in order to access the `webpack.config.js` as required.

So the questions are:

- How do I setup `webpack-dev-middleware` with HapiJS in conjunction with `create-react-app`?
- How do I access the `webpack.config.js` without ejecting (and preferably without using any 3rd party modules)?

> NOTE: This is not Server Side Rendering, I am using HapiJS as a proxy since there are cross-domain API calls involved and the proxy helps me avoid the infamous CORS error and serve the application as well.